# My UITabBarController's didSelectViewController method is not getting called?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, callback, uitabbarcontroller

Here is my code stub for my app-delegate.m -- it never gets called.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

It is defined in this app-delegate.h

```
@interface OrioleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

Comment: Nevermind, i forgot to set the delegate -- oops.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you make a connection between your `UITabBarController` and your application delegate?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
     ...
     tabBarController.delegate = self;
     ...
}
```

Comment: Yup -- I forgot and you were too quick :))  Thanks for the super-light-speed response.

Comment: Hell, I tried, this solution and didn't work.  Are either of you abel to help?  I put my code here: Hello, i am have a similar problem. I've posted my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891182/iphone-how-to-implement-didselectvie‌​wcontroller/10891264.

Answer (score 15):

If your ViewController is a `UITabBarController`, you need to set self as it's delegate because you can't change the delegate of the `UITabBar` directly.

For example, in the ViewDidLoad of your `UITabBarController` :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: ya its working for me too... actually I had tried it before and then search for this to check is it correct way or not and I got your answer so ...

Comment: This is working for me as well. I'm using this in an extended UITabBarController class, and in my case I initially got a compiler Warning saying: "Assigning to 'id<UITabBarControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ECMainTabBarViewController *const __strong'". I fixed that by casting the delegate to type (id), as follows:     self.delegate = (id)self;

Answer (score 0):

I added the following `tabBarController.delegate = self;` and all is well.  I hope this is helpful to others.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I made sure that I have delegate set up as:

tabBarController.delegate = self;

but still the delegate methods are not being called.

Comment: check for conflicts from your IB definition.  what class are you defining in the builder and is it hooked up to your cod correctly?