# When Press Tabbar But it's not going to it"s Rootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

When i press certain Tab it's not going to its rootviewcontroller,

When user changes a tab, for the selected tab I want to push it to its top level controller.

I have implement this method but not works,

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *) tabBarController didSelectViewController : (UIViewController *)viewController
{
   [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

What's wrong with this?

How can i do that?

Comment: Did you set your delegate? 

Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530266/my-uitabbarcontrollers-didselectviewcontroller-method-is-not-getting-called

Comment: Yes,I set the UITabBarControllerDelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the method gets called (if not you should set the UITabBarController delegate), you are probably receiving the UINavigationController (which is a subclass of UIViewController) as viewController, you can check by logging it:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *) tabBarController didSelectViewController : (UIViewController *)viewController
{
   NSLog(@"didSelect %@", viewController);
   [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

if that is the case, viewController.navigationController will probably be nil, you should be doing:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *) tabBarController didSelectViewController : (UIViewController *)viewController
{   
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```